# Pyueye IDS Camera

Tags: ids, ueye

I am working with IDS camera and they have a python module called pyueye. I installed it using pip, but it seems like the dll are missing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyueye/dll.py", line 166, in load_dll
    dll = DLL(libinfo, libnames, os.getenv(envname))
  File "/home/bikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyueye/dll.py", line 96, in __init__
    raise RuntimeError("could not find any library for {} ({})".format(libinfo, dllmsg))
RuntimeError: could not find any library for ueye_api (DLL_PATH: unset)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bikram/Documents/uEye/1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pyueye import ueye
  File "/home/bikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyueye/__init__.py", line 56, in <module>
    from . import ueye
  File "/home/bikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyueye/ueye.py", line 58, in <module>
    get_dll_file, _bind = load_dll("ueye_api", ["ueye_api_64", "ueye_api"], "PYUEYE_DLL_PATH")
  File "/home/bikram/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyueye/dll.py", line 168, in load_dll
    raise ImportError(exc)
ImportError: could not find any library for ueye_api (DLL_PATH: unset)
```

I noticed someone else had the same issue in windows.
Does anyone else have the same issue using pyeue?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but then I downloaded IDS Software Suite from https://en.ids-imaging.com/
Installed it and everything worked. Give it a try.

It will also let you configure their camera from IDS Camera Manager before you use it from Python.